# Rails Struct to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I've created a custom class based on a simple struct and I need to get it back in JSON:

```
    class ItemTag <
      Struct.new(:id, :item_id, :type, :subtype, :top, :left, :height, :width, :name, :alternate, :photo_url, :price, :quantity, :comment, :memo)
      def to_map
        map = Hash.new
        self.members.each { |m| map[m] = self[m] }
        map
      end

      def to_json(*a)
        to_map.to_json(*a)
      end
    end
```

In my controller, I'm collecting this data like so:

```
@tags = design.item_links.all.map{ |pi| ItemTag.new(pi.id,pi.item_id,pi.item.type,pi.item.subtype,pi.top,pi.left,pi.height,pi.width,pi.item.name,pi.item.alternate_name,pi.item.logo_photo(:thumb),pi.price,pi.quantity,pi.public_note,pi.private_note)}
```

and finally, in my view, i need this data as a json string to pass into a javascript function so I do:

```
<%= raw(@tags.to_json) %>
```

the the output I get though looks like this:

```
[[\"1b245b45\",\"444dc0e6\",\"plant\",\"cactus\",94,661,110,174,\"Blue mistflower\",\"conoclinium coelestinum\",\" \",56.0,4,\"test\",\"test\"],[\"21e8db0c\",\"3097c392\",\"plant\",\"bamboo\",128,108,161,100,\"Green and gold\",\"chrysogonum virginianum\",\" \",76.0,5,\"this is very green\",\"dont tell them it has gold\"]]
```

If I put the to_json inside of my map action in the controller, it generates valid json for each record, but it won't give me the array of all objects as JSON.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
def as_json(*a)
  to_map
end
```

The as_json method in ruby is like the to_json function in JavaScript. It returns data that's prepared to be serialized, rather than serialized data.